# responder chain goes subview to superview, what about scrollview?

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, touch, first-responder

From [apple doc](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/EventsiPhoneOS/EventsiPhoneOS.html)
subview(near to the screen) gets to handle a touch event first than their superviews.

On the other hand, views are added to a scroll view as a subview but the scroll view handles touch to detect swipes first.

Can I treat the scrollview case as a special case?

Comment: Check out the WWDC videos on scroll views, they discuss this sort of thing

Comment: ah thanks, I should watch the video, I keep forgetting bringing my headset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't forget this part:

> If the hit-test view cannot handle the event, the event travels up the
>   responder chain as described in “Responder Objects and the Responder
>   Chain” until the system finds a view that can handle it.

if your sub-view can't handle it, it will be passed to the `UIScrollView`.